# Dynamically built Javascript src attribute error in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, src

Controller

```
public ActionResult GetCategories()
    {

        var htmlText = new StringBuilder();
        var scriptText = new StringBuilder();

        htmlText.Append("Hello world");
        scriptText.AppendFormat("document.write({0});", htmlText.ToString());
        var content = new ContentResult();
        content.Content = scriptText.ToString();
        return content;
    }
```

View

```
<script src="/Home/GetCategories" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"/>
```

It runs well on FF, but not in IE.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work ...in general, you should read Appendix C of the XHTML1 spec before using XHTML features like self-closing tags in old-school-HTML. http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#guidelines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `script` tag needs a closing tag to be compliant.  IE actually obeys the standard in this respect while FF is more forgiving.  Change your view to:

```
<script src="/Home/GetCategories" type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
</script>
```